# jQuery AJAX - limitations, security, anti-cross-domain

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am kind of confused about security information about jQuery AJAX. I am developing an ADD-ON for CMS. There are jQuery AJAX calls for PHP file `EXECUTE.PHP`. 
Now I would like to sell my ADD-ON and here are the questions:

1. My ADD-ON will buy two customers `A)John (nice guy), B)Bruce (the hacker)`. They both know the structure of my koding, file locations, files content - EVERYTHING. What if Bruce will change AJAX calls to the `EXECUTE.PHP` file of the John's server. Bruce knows that the CMS is ussualy installed on `WWW.DOMAIN-NAME.COM/CMS`, so he can suspect the location of `EXECUTE.PHP` on the server of John. Is it possible to do this? The `EXECUTE.PHP` file can delete entries in the DB - so is Bruce able to delete all the DB entries with loop like `"DELETE FROM ... WHERE ID = [1, 2, 3 ..]"`? Is it possible with cross domain access (John has his own domain and Bruce has his own and different domain)? What I can do to prevent it? Are there any other risks?
2. When Bruce will call `EXECUTE.PHP` on John's server and the `EXECUTE.PHP` file returns address via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - what address it will return. It will be John's address or address of Bruce there is the AJAX call?

Thank you very much for all the answers and help.

Comment: I'm afraid this is likely to be closed as a question that can't so much be answered as merely discussed. SO is more for code-specific questions.

Comment: Add  some code so we can understand clearly

Answer (score 0):

First thing to keep in mind , JQuery is client side. We cannot secure it, because anyone can access it. All logic's,methods, coding is accessible.

For cross domain methodology, there are two methods to handle this.
1. JSONP
2. CORS

Try to have a look on this, and use appropriate one, rather than make it public.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your `execute.php`-file should have checks to see if any access comes from the same domain it's currently in. Then it should check and see if the access comes from a logged in user with admin-rights (which I assume one needs to modify the database, or at least should need), and that the username that is being used is the one that is logged in (and that a user is actually logged in). That will prevent most of the problems you mention.
Any kind of data-manipulation can be manipulated, the best solution is to make it as secure as you possibly can, perhaps by allowing a selection of user-logins with access in the plugin's admin-interface. That way you can pinpoint which user should have access to make changes.

The REQUEST_URI can be forged, but as standard, it will show the `hacker`'s IP/domain.